# QGIS 3 Deleting Neighbour Points

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have two Excel-Files (and after import two layers) where points are stored. They are around 2-4m away from each other.

How can I **delete**, or better, merge them to one point on map and on (fully) export to Excel again?

How to export to Excel with coordinates included in this file?

Comment: Do those points in both Excel files share an `"id"` in common? Can you please show how those points look like in QGIS? If you have two points at *"one location"* ("around 2-4m away from each other") attributes have to be merged that is obvious but which coordinates of location have to be kept otherwise how do you define the correct location?

Comment: You could decide, which layer is in the correct location, and then use `join by nearest` so it joins only one point, and only if the other point is 5 m away.